# Log Error Details for Wordpress Website

Tags: php, wordpress

Last night i got a mail from my website server host. In that they strictly server suspension warning due to high server load. Currently my website has not too much traffic but i'm using a plugin for data upload.

LOG FILE ERROR IS:

| 6820 | contactn_contact | localhost | contactn_bhuvan | Query          | 619  | Sending data       | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE |

HERE IS THE MAIL WHICH I RECEIVED FROM HOSTING SERVER

We have gone through your issue and found that, your database has disabled due to high load on the server, please check the logs as below:

| 6820 | contactn_contact | localhost | contactn_bhuvan | Query          | 619  | Sending data       | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE |
| 6856 | contactn_contact | localhost | contactn_bhuvan | Query          | 554  | Sending data       | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE |
| 6903 | contactn_contact | localhost | contactn_bhuvan | Query          | 619  | Sending data       | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE |
| 6904 | contactn_contact | localhost | contactn_bhuvan | Query          | 554  | Sending data       | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE |
| 6917 | contactn_contact | localhost | contactn_bhuvan | Query          | 603  | Sending data       | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE |
| 6920 | contactn_contact | localhost | contactn_bhuvan | Query          | 590  | Sending data       | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: how i optimize my code for my website... or anybody know existing optimized code for wordpress wp_term_taxonomy section

Comment: One of your plugins gets your data and tries to send somewhere. This might be a backup plugin sends your daily data to your email. Have you got any plugin like that?

Comment: no i'dnt have... i use a plugin for csv upload. And i upload cvs through that on daily basis.

Comment: However, it seems, it tries to send data sequentally, not daily basis.